# Pandas datareader has no attribute

Tags: python, pandas, ta-lib

So i'm trying to use this simple code to test TA-Lib and the other modules, but i'm having some problems:

```
from pandas_datareader import data, wb
import datetime
import talib
import numpy


start = datetime.datetime(2010,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime(2014,3,24)
ticker = "AAPL"
f = wb.pandas_datareader(ticker,'yahoo',start,end)

f['SMA_20'] = talib.SMA(numpy.asarray(f['Close']), 20)
f['SMA_50'] = talib.SMA(numpy.asarray(f['Close']), 50)
f.plot(y= ['Close','SMA_20','SMA_50'], title='AAPL Close & Moving Averages')
```

Gets the error `AttributeError: module 'pandas_datareader.wb' has no attribute 'pandas_datareader'`
I successfully installed pandas-datareader, but i keep getting the error, did anyone else experience this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the particular syntax you're using, but the way given here works fine for me: http://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html

Comment: Taking a look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the line `f = wb.pandas_datareader(ticker,'yahoo',start,end)`,  `wb` has no `pandas_datareader` within it. That is what your error says.

If you are looking at https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#yahoo-finance, then you should note that they import `pandas_datareader.data` with the alias `web`. In your case it has no alias, so you can call it with `data`.

I can guess that you are trying to do `f = data.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo',start,end)`

Comment: Well, i tried that but i get 'pandas_datareader' is not defined'

Comment: Sorry...my bad. You should use only wb() without pandas_datareader.

Comment: So i tried again and the previous problem seems to be solved, but right now i'm getting the error 'module object is not callable', did i make mistakes on the first line, calling pandas?

Comment: No, first line is ok. You imported data and wb there. Now the new problem is that wb is not a function. Maybe you need something from wb, but I have no  idea what. Could you explain how you got this code?

Comment: The new edit solved the problem, but it gave me the error 'Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access'

Comment: I got the code here: http://www.lampdev.org/programming/python/ta-lib-setup-and-example.html , i'm getting started to data analysis with Python and i had a bad time installing TA-Lib, so i searched for a quick example to see if TA-Lib was working properly!

Comment: I believe your new error is with another line in the code. Is it?

Comment: Yeah. 'line 1716
    series.name = label'